# Configure spray-json for non strict parsing deserialization

Tags: json, scala, spray, spray-json

How to configure the spray-json parsing on parsing options? 
Similarly as [Jackson Parsing Features](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/wiki/JsonParser-Features).

For example, I am parsing a json that has a field that my case class has not, and it is breaking:

```
spray.json.DeserializationException: Object is missing required member 'myfield'
```

**UPDATE** :

A simple example:

```
case class MyClass(a: String, b: Long);
```

and try to parse an incomplete json like

```
val data = "{a: \"hi\"}"
```

with a spray-json format like:

```
jsonFormat2(MyClass.apply)
// ...
data.parseJson.convertTo[MyClass]
```

(simplified code).

But the question goes further, I want to ask about configuration options like in other parsers. More examples:

- Be able to ignore fields that exist in the JSON but not in the case class.
- Ways of managing nulls or nonexistent values.
  etc.

Comment: post an example of your case class and your json.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch Updated with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SprayJson allows you to define custom parsers like so:

```
case class Foo(a: String, b: Int)
implicit object FooJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Foo] {
  override def read(json: JsValue): Foo = {
    json.asJsObject.getFields("name", "id") match {
      case Seq(JsString(name), id) =>
        Foo(name, id.convertTo[Int])
    }
  }

  override def write(obj: Foo): JsValue = obj.toJson
}
```

This allows you to parse any arbitrary payload and pull out the fields "name" and "id" - other fields are ignored. If those fields are not guaranteed you can add something like:

```
      case Seq(JsString(name), JsNull) =>
        Foo(name, 0)
```

You should look at what's available in [JsValue.scala](https://github.com/spray/spray-json/blob/master/src/main/scala/spray/json/JsValue.scala) - in particular `JsArray` may come in handy if you're getting payloads with anonymous arrays (i.e. the root is `[{...}]` instead of `{"field":"value"...}`)

Comment: Right. I was expecting not to have to do it by hand (like Jackson's ObjectMapper `mapper.readValue[T](json)` and be able to configure it via some kind of [DeserializationFeature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html) or so, but I see it's not possible, then.

Answer (score 1):

Spray Json doesn't support default parameters. So You cannot have a case class like

```
case class MyClass(a: String, b: Int = 0)
```

and then parse json like `{"a":"foo"}`

However if you make the second parameter as Option. then it works.

```
  import spray.json._
  case class MyClass(a: String, b: Option[Int] = None)
  object MyProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val f = jsonFormat2(MyClass)
  }
  import MyProtocol.f
  val mc1 = MyClass("foo", Some(10))
  val strJson = mc1.toJson.toString
  val strJson2 = """{"a": "foo"}"""
  val mc2 = strJson2.parseJson.convertTo[MyClass]
  println(mc2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Right, this works around the specific allow-nulls problem with a Scala language feature. However, what about the other options, or the typical JSON parsing configurations? Is there no way to configure the parser/mapper? If that's true, it looks like quite a limited parser choice compared to other parsers (like abovementioned Jackson or others).